# Rails 3 Checking a relationship count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User & Profile Models. A user has_one profile IE.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  # Relationships
  has_one :profile

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Relationships
  belongs_to :user
```

I am then trying to test to see if the user has a profile. If not redirect them to the profile controller ie.

```
class User::BaseController < ApplicationController

  # Filters
  before_filter :check_for_profile

  # Layout
  layout "backend"

  # Helpers
  helper_method :current_user

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def check_for_profile
    if current_user.profile.empty?
      redirect_to new_user_profile_path, :notice => "Please create a profile first."
    end
  end

end
```

No matter what I try I'm getting the error.

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.empty?
```

I'm pretty sure my relationships are right. Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance.

Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `profile.blank?` instead.  `empty?` is not defined for `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "blank?" method at the following link. The "present?" method should also be considered - they're basically the same.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F